# Symbol of self-adjoint pseudodifferential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

It seems that the following result should hold, but I can't find it explicitly anywhere. If $A=A^*$ is a properly supported pseudodifferential operator, does this imply that $\sigma_A(x,\xi)=\sigma_{A^*}(x,\xi)$? More specifically, is the symbol of $A$ real?

I know that the asymptotic expansion of $\sigma_{A^*}$ is given from the asymptotic expansion of $\sigma_A$ as
$$
\sum_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}D^{\alpha}\overline{\sigma_{A}(x,\xi)}\cdot \frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

Comment: If $A = A^\ast$, shouldn't the symbols of $A$ and $A^\ast$ be the same, simply because they're precisely the same operator?

Comment: Well yes, what I really should be asking is whether it implies that the symbol of $A$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

This is true. As noted in the comments, it is (of course) true that if two operators are equal, then their principal symbols are equal. Otherwise, it would be ill-defined. Then, you clarified that you wanted to know if the principal symbol is necessarily real, and this is also true. The principal symbol of the adjoint is the complex conjugate of the principal symbol, i.e. $\sigma_{A^*}=\overline{\sigma_A}.$ Since $A^*=A,$ it follows that $\sigma_A=\sigma_{A^*},$ i.e. $\sigma_A=\overline{\sigma_A}.$ Thus, $$\text{Im }\sigma_A=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\sigma_A-\overline{\sigma_A}\right)=0,$$ implying that $\sigma_A$ is real. The full symbol need not be real, as the principal symbol is only defined up to a symbol of a lower order (i.e. if $A\in OPS^m,$ then $\sigma_A\in S^m/S^{m-1}$).

Comment: I think you are missing a minus sign. If $A=i\frac{d}{dx}$ then $A$ is self-adjoint but the symbol is $i\xi$, which is skew-adjoint.

Comment: @geometricK That's also not the correct symbol for $A$. It should be $-\xi$. You can check this using the Fourier transform.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue of convention. I'm going by the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator

Comment: @geometricK Indeed, what they wrote is misleading. They are embedding a $1/i$ in each derivative they take without mentioning it (hence the capital $D$). It is standard to do this, though. As you noticed, you will get inconsistencies otherwise. In particular, it's not consistent with the Fourier transform perspective otherwise. See page 12 of this webpage, for example, for proper definitions: https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~jwunsch/micronotes.pdf

Comment: I see. It's interesting that one still sees the other convention in some situations, for example on Example 2.1.6 (p. 49) and Cor 2.1.15 (p. 52) of: https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/ind-thm.pdf. I do see that in your convention, the symbol of the Laplacian would be positive, whereas in the other convention it would be negative; I wonder why the difference.

Comment: @geometricK Hm, those notes are outside of my area of expertise. I'm guessing that it's contextual, but I'm not sure. The author of those notes is active on MathOverflow. You could potentially pose the question on there and tag them (username is their full name iirc) if you'd like a reason for the conventional differences.